# How prioritize the messages in azure Eventhub?

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Is there a way to prioritize a message in azure event hub? Right now all the messages are going in first in first out order. I want some are high priority messages to be processed first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot. It is not designed that way.

However, there is a thing called [consumer groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups):

> A consumer group is a view (state, position, or offset) of an entire event hub. Consumer groups enable multiple consuming applications to each have a separate view of the event stream, and to read the stream independently at their own pace and with their own offsets.

This enables you to create a consumer group named, say, "HighPrio" and attach readers to that consumer group. Then when messages come in you skip the low prio message handling by just doing nothing with them and process (complex) logic on high prio messages. By skipping the logic for low prio messages the readers will advance quicker through the message stream that the default consumer group.